# Python Multiprocessing 2d Array Input

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing

I am trying to create a process pool using multiprocessing with 2d array arguments using starmap. However, the arguments seem to be input row by row instead of element by element.

What I would like is to use each element to create a 3d output array with an array corresponding to each element in the 2d input array

I've created a simplified code to illustrate what I mean:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

MeshNumberY = 5
MeshNumberX = 10

result_list = np.zeros( (MeshNumberX,MeshNumberY,3) )

Xindices = np.tile(np.arange(MeshNumberX),(MeshNumberY,1))
Yindices = np.tile(np.reshape(np.arange(MeshNumberY),(MeshNumberY,1)),(1,MeshNumberX))

def image_pixel_array(x,y):
    return np.array([5*x,5*y,255])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    result_list = np.array(pool.starmap(image_pixel_array, zip(Xindices, Yindices)))
    print(result_list)
```

The input arrays Xindices and Yindices were,

```
[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]]
```

and

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4]]
```

respectively, with the corresponding output being,

```
[[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
  array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]) 255]
 [array([5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5])
  array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]) 255]
 [array([10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10])
  array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]) 255]
 [array([15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15])
  array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]) 255]
 [array([20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20])
  array([ 0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45]) 255]]
```

My goal is to receive an output more like,

```
[[[0 0 255] [5 0 255] [10 0 255] [15 0 255] [20 0 255] [25 0 255] [30 0 255] [35 0 255] [40 0 255] [45 0 255]]
[[[0 5 255] [5 5 255] [10 5 255] [15 5 255] [20 5 255] [25 5 255] [30 5 255] [35 5 255] [40 5 255] [45 5 255]]
etc.
```

If there's a suggestion to optimize how I set up my arrays it would certainly also be welcome as I'm fairly new to this.

This was all written in Python 3.7.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Iteration is on the first dimension of an array, in your 2d case by rows.  Test this with `for x in arr:...`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

MeshNumberY = 5
MeshNumberX = 10

result_list = np.zeros( (MeshNumberX,MeshNumberY,3) )

Xindices = np.tile(np.arange(MeshNumberX),(MeshNumberY,1))
Yindices = np.tile(np.reshape(np.arange(MeshNumberY),(MeshNumberY,1)),(1,MeshNumberX))
Zindices = Yindices.copy()

def image_pixel_array(x,y,z):

    return np.transpose([5*x,5*y,z*0+255])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    result_list = np.array(pool.starmap(image_pixel_array, zip(Xindices, Yindices,Zindices)))
    print(np.reshape(result_list,(MeshNumberY,MeshNumberX,3),order='F'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It works fine but for my actual code I have varying amounts of input arrays. Is there a way to generalize this for any amount of arguments? I'm also not sure why individual elements are taken as arguments here instead of rows as in my code.

Comment: print(np.reshape(result_list,(MeshNumberY,MeshNumberX,3),order='F')) change into print(result_list) still works fine,